# JSON object to "array"

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I'm using plot.ly and it wants data structured like this:

```
var data = [
  {
    x: [cow, horse, chicken]
    y: [20, 14, 23],
    type: 'bar'
  }
```

I'm using the following to get data from mySQL:

```
$.getJSON('get_data.php', function(data) {
    console.log(data); //returns JSON object
    var ticks6 =[]

    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
         var myvalues= [val.category];
         ticks6.push( myvalues  );
    });
```

This doesn't format the data correctly, as I just end up with an array, but not the values in the array. I feel like I need `map`, but I'm not quite sure how to use it in this case.

Comment: can you show us what `data` looks like when entering the function? (i.e. the output of `console.log(data);` like you do already)

Comment: It comes like this: ``[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0
:
Object
category
:
"Building"
total
:
12038
__proto__
:
Object //etc``

Comment: And what do those objects inside look like?

Comment: @mjohnsonengr Hard to do the formatting here, but this one: ``Object category : "Building" total : 12038 __proto__ : Object``

Comment: @jonmrich Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(data)` and then paste that into the question.

Comment: @mjohnsonengr I'm trying to end up with something like ``[bob, tom, jim, mike]``

Comment: plot.ly wants an array of objects, but you're setting `ticks6` to an array of array of object.

Comment: @Barmar Makes sense...how do I fix that?

Comment: Paste the data as a JSON string; that'd make it easier to interpret...

Comment: Why are you doing `myvalues = [val.category]`? That puts the category into a nested array. Why not just `ticks6.push(val.category)`.

Comment: @Barmar That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding an extra level of array wrapping that you don't need when you do `[val.category]`. Don't do that, just push the category directly onto the array.

```
$.getJSON('get_data.php', function(data) {
    console.log(data); //returns JSON object
    var ticks6 =[]

    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
         ticks6.push( val.category  );
    });
```

You can also use:

```
var ticks6 = data.map(function(function(val) {
    return val.category;
});
```

And in Ecmascript 6 this can be shortened to:

```
var ticks6 = data.map(v => v.category);
```